# Adding columns to a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the below data frame:

```
  Name      id   Quiz1 Exam1 Exam2 Quiz2 Exam3
1 Susan   123412  50    47    33    67    79
2 John    548963  38    61    75    59    65
3 Bob     234563  89    97    85    88    92
4 Bill    429591  72    73    74    75    76
5 Mary    245887  92    95    79    89    90
6 Paul    97522   99     3    55    60    72
```

and want to add 2 columns. Quiz Average and Exam Average. I have been having a hard time getting any code to work, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this...?

```
> transform(df, 
+           QuizAverage=rowMeans(cbind(Quiz1, Quiz2)),
+           ExamAverage=rowMeans(cbind(Exam1, Exam2, Exam3)))
   Name     id Quiz1 Exam1 Exam2 Quiz2 Exam3 QuizAverage ExamAverage
1 Susan 123412    50    47    33    67    79        58.5    53.00000
2  John 548963    38    61    75    59    65        48.5    67.00000
3   Bob 234563    89    97    85    88    92        88.5    91.33333
4  Bill 429591    72    73    74    75    76        73.5    74.33333
5  Mary 245887    92    95    79    89    90        90.5    88.00000
6  Paul  97522    99     3    55    60    72        79.5    43.33333
```

Comment: YES, Thank you! My professor made this very confusing to understand but that code makes total sense.

Comment: Are there any functions (like rowMeans) to calculate standard deviation in R?

Comment: Yes, there are, see `rowSds()` from matrixStats package, read this package helpfile to learn about a lot of functions to be applied rowise. Also you can use `apply(data.frame, 1, sd)` from R base.

Comment: You can automate this somewhat too by using `grep`: `transform(df, QuizAvg = rowMeans(df[grep("Quiz", names(df))]), ExamAvg = rowMeans(df[grep("Exam", names(df))]))`.

Answer (score 1):

The transform function does get the job done, but creating columns in R can be accomplished very easily without the use of the transform function.

Adding your columns can also be accomplished by:

```
> df$QuizAverage = (df$Quiz1 + df$Quiz2) / 2

> df$ExamAverage = (df$Exam1 + df$Exam2 + df$Exam3) / 3
```

This site provides a pretty good reference for manipulating dataframes.
[HowToinR.weebly.com](http://howtoinr.weebly.com/merging-data.html)

Comment: @J's answer requires three functions (transform, rowmeans, cbind), the one above requires none. 

For programming it is typically better to use the standard subsetting arithmetic functions.

And for users just learning R there is inherent value in learning how to execute without the use of 'convenience' functions.

Comment: To each his own, I guess. Your approach strikes me as potentially very tedious, cumbersome to convert into a program (for general use or application over a larger dataset), not to just answer the question asked), and potentially error prone (as in your case with the missing `/`).

Comment: Ha! My haste knows no bounds. Thanks.